# Story ID young adult sci fi novel

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, powers

I read this book that I can't remember much about, it's this teen guy who discovers he has psychic powers. I remember he lives in a shitty house, and he has lots of anger issues. He breaks his TV at some point, pretty sure he only has his mom. I remember that something happens and police start to try and arrest him and he gets in a fight with police and ends up having to defend himself. There's  a tornado and he ends up saving people from it. I remember at some point it describes him as glowing from his chest, like his powers are getting stronger and his whole body is glowing.

Comment: This is a great start for a story ID question.  Just a few ideas to narrow down your search:  When did you read this book?  Was it in English?  Any idea when it was published?  Any and all details are useful!